# Webview not constraining to bottom of view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some difficulty making my webview stick to the bottom of it's superview. I'm resizing the webview based on it's content height and would like it to "grow" up while being constrained against a bottom marker. You can see what I mean from these two images (webview blacked out):

[image]

[image]

I have tried a few things. This is what I'm using to resizing my webview, and then attempting to get it to constrain to it's superview.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    print("got here")
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView.superview, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    webView.superview!.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
}
```

Unfortunately, the webview still extends down as opposed to up. I always want the webview to be against the bottom of the mapview, which has it's bottom at the top of the tab bar. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many times "got here" gets printed? Also, are you sure it's superview is the size you want? Try changing background colors to help checking out views sizes.